# adding data to database faster

Tags: jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I am using JSF on JAVA EE with netbeans. I read a file line by line with a buffer reader to add the data to my database. It works properly but it is very long waiting time because I have one million of lines.
To add the data to my database I am using the function persist which is in the interface Entity Manager (generated).
I would like to know if there would be a way to make it faster ? Using big transactions maybe?

Thanks,
Best Regards.

Comment: Can you batch the inserts in groups? Batches help improve performance by much.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Indeed, where the function persist is we can not modify the code.

Comment: Might be some useful info on batch inserts in this question: [batch-inserts-using-jpa-entitymanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584179/batch-inserts-using-jpa-entitymanager)

Comment: JPA is not the best choice to do bulk insert, but you could make a multi-thread procedure: read and write portion of file in 4/5 threads like Java Batch partitions does