# Bulk insert with JPA criteria builder

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpa-criteria

I currently a spring boot project with postgres and hibernate and had the following functions:

```
  private fun savePost(post: Post): Post = entityManager.merge(post)

  private fun savePosts(posts: List<Post>) = 
       posts.forEach { save(post) }
```

I wanted to avoid a sequential insert so now I have a raw query:

```
 private fun savePosts(posts: List<Post>) {
      val queryText: String = createTextQueryFromList(posts)
      val query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryText)
      query.executeUpdate()
 }
```

This does work but it is not very clean.

What is the correct way for a bulk insert using criteria builder?

Answer (score 0):

The first option would be to iterate over the posts and flush a batch of updates and release memory.
The last answer here:
[Batch inserts using JPA EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584179/batch-inserts-using-jpa-entitymanager) says JPA by itself does not have any settings for batching. However there are some implementation-dependent settings. [Here is an example for hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).
See **13.2. Batch updates**

The other option would be to try `session.doWork()`
See example https://keyurj.blogspot.com/2012/12/dowork-in-hibernate.html

Comment: Hello, The answer you provided me with applies to JPA repositories. I don't have any repositories (classes which implement the JPA repository interface) and instead, am utilizing an entity manager. Could you please elaborate on how I can apply the suggested scenario to my case?