# Spring Data JPA batch insert

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, batch-processing

I have 1,000,000 records to enter into a database.  I have an arrayList of all million records. 
 I then run a for loop to break the arrayList into smaller lists of 1,000 items and do a save all.  The first group of 1,000 inserts in under a second, then every batch of 1,000 takes longer and longer to run, within 100,000  records it takes over a minute to save. If I stop the program and pick up where it left off the first batch again inserts in under a second then the time per insert grows.  Below is pseudocode

```
ArrayList<Student> students= getAllRecords();
int skip =1000;

for (int i = (int) (repository.count() + 1); i < students.size(); i += skip) 
{
    List<String> subStudents = students.subList(i, Math.min(i + skip, students.size()));
    studentRepository.saveAll(subStudents);
}
```

Comment: Batching is done on a JPA level which is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584179/batch-inserts-using-jpa-entitymanager/31020939

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do bulk (multi row) inserts with JpaRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772230/how-to-do-bulk-multi-row-inserts-with-jparepository)